# flask app Failed to serve js generate from vite. Error: Failed to load module script

Tags: python, node.js, flask, azure-web-app-service, vite

I have a webapp where the backend is build with python (flask) and the frontend is build with nodejs.

For the frontend, I run the following to generate static files:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

This is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; // Use PORT environment variable if available, otherwise use 5000 as a fallback

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    base: "/static/",
    build: {
        outDir: "../backend/static",
        emptyOutDir: true,
        sourcemap: true
    },
    envPrefix: ["APP_INSIGHTS_CONN_STRING", "VITE_"],
    envDir: "../../.azure/myenv/",
    server: {
        proxy: {
            "/abc": `http://localhost:${port}`,
            "/xyz": `http://localhost:${port}`,
            "/lmn": `http://localhost:${port}`,
            "/wuv": `http://localhost:${port}`
        }
    }
});
```

I then have the generate static file as part of my deployed package. I zip it and use zip deployment to deploy to Azure.
The code structure in the wwwroot folder in azure is like that:

```
wwwroot
  - static
  - app.py
  - requirements.txt
  ...other irrelevant files and folders
```

In app.py, I have the following code to serve the frontend files

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return send_from_directory('static', 'index.html')

@app.route("/<path:path>")
def static_file(path):
    return app.send_static_file(path)
```

When this is deployed, the backend seems to be working fine, but the static files do not seem to be served correctly. I get a white page, when I inspected it, it is the index that is generated by vite, but apparently the js and css files are not rendered/served and I get the below error: Failed to load modile script: Expected a Javascript module script but the server responses with a MIME tyoe of "text/html". strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

what am I doing wrong? I tried to remove the "base" parameter from vite, still same error.

Also when I click on the js, it doesn't open

[image]

Comment: How you are deploying your WebApp?

Answer (score 0):

*I tried a sample code with Vite and Python. I was able to see the static files after deployment to the Azure web app.*

**backend/app.py :**

```py
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
 
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return send_from_directory('static', 'index.html')
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def static_file(path):
    return app.send_static_file(path)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**frontend/vite.config.ts :**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default {
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: "../../backend/static",
    emptyOutDir: true,
    sourcemap: true,
  },
};
```

**index.html :**

```html
<!doctype  html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
<meta  charset="UTF-8"  />
<link  rel="icon"  type="image/svg+xml"  href="/vite.svg"  />
<meta  name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"  />
<title>Vite + React</title>
</head>
<body>
<div  id="root"></div>
<script  type="module"  src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Below is the frontend local output :***

[image]

***Below is the backend local output :***

[image]

It deployed successfully as below,

[image]

I got the web app output as below.

[image]